# Compare code for twice entries

Tags: php

If i've database `my_table (id,word)` as following

[image: my_table (id,word)]

and i've some posted text called 
`$name` and `$comment` then i want to know if `$name` and/or `$comment` have any words like words i've stored in my database `my_table (id,word)`

```
$name = "Manal Nor";
$comment = "Hello lovely world";
```

I can now apply it for only one entry for example `$name`

```
$name = "Manal Nor"; // As example no bad words

$sql    = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$nameArray = explode(" ", $name);
$countname = count($nameArray);
$checkname = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    for ($i=0;$i<$countname;$i++) {

        if (strcasecmp($nameArray[$i], $row['word']) == 0) {
            $checkname = 1;
        }

    }

}

if ($checkname == 1) {
    echo "banned";
    exit;
}
else {
    echo "passed";
}
```

but **now the question** how to apply it for both `$name` and/or `$comment` so that i can give `echo "banned";` if either `$name` and/or `$comment` have any of the bad words in `my_table`

Comment: This question would have been just as clear without actual profanity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here would be to split both variables on word characters with `preg_split()` and use the resultant arrays to form an `IN()` clause to your query.

```
// Strip non-alpha, space characters
$name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z ]/", "", $name);
$comment = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z ]/", "", $comment);

$namewords = explode(" ", $name);
$commentwords = explode(" ", $comment);
// Stick them together and escape
$allwords = array_merge($namewords, $commentwords);

// Surround each word in quotes
$allwords = array_unique($allwords);
$allwords = array_map(function($w) {return "'$w'";}, $allwords);
$allwords = implode(",", $allwords);    

// Builds a query like 
// SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE word IN ('all', 'words', 'from', 'comment', 'and', 'name');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT word FROM my_table WHERE word IN($allwords)");

if ($result) {
   // If any rows were returned, the input contained a bad word.
   if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      // Contains bad words.  Ban user.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add worlds from the comment too. Replace the original line with

```
$nameArray = array_merge(explode(" ", $name), explode(" ", $comment));
```